# How to target a specific query from functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use offset on a specific WP_Query on a page that has a total of 3 Loops with the code described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination#Offset_.26_Manual_Pagination).

For now, this works but I can only target all three loops. What (I think) I have to do is change this part:

```
//Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if ( ! $query->is_posts_page ) {
        return;
    }
```

To something like this:

```
//Before anything else, make sure this is the right query...
    if ( ! $query->$THELOOPIWANTTOTARGET ) {
        return;
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

The query:

```html
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $mainloop = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged));

    ?>
    <div class="full padding center isotope">
    <?php if ( $mainloop->have_posts() ) :  while ( $mainloop->have_posts() ) : $mainloop->the_post();  ?>
      <article class="post">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <div class="textwrap">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
          <?php if ( get_field('bron')): ?>
            <?php  if ( get_field('bron')): ?><a href="<?php the_field('bron_link'); ?>" target="_blank" class="source"><?php endif; ?>
              <?php the_field('bron'); ?>
            <?php  if ( get_field('bron')): ?></a><?php endif; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="readmore">
          <div class="fa fa-share share" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="share_block"><div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></div></div>
          </div>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="readmorebutton">Lees verder</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    
    <?php else : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you already have? I think it is the other way around: $THELOOPYOUWANTTOTARGET->is_post_page

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've added the query.

I just tried $mainloop->is_post_page, but that didn't work...